# What accounts for different execution times between HeidiSQL and SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, heidisql

When I execute a particular query from Heidi against an MSSQL database, it takes approximately 10 times longer than executing the identical query in SSMS.

They are both being executed against the same server from the same workstation.

What can account for this difference?

Here is the exact query and relative execution times:

```
SELECT b.ID as BookingID, b.ReservationID, b.RoomID, b.EventName, 
b.EventTypeID, b.StatusID, b.DateAdded, build.Value1 as BuildingID, 
build.ValueDescription as Building
FROM EMS.dbo.tblBooking b
INNER JOIN EMS.dbo.tblRoom room
ON room.ID = b.RoomID
INNER JOIN (    SELECT      deff.Value1, deff.ValueDescription
FROM        tblDataExtractionFilter_Fields deff
INNER JOIN  tblDataExtractionFilter def ON deff.FilterID = def.ID
WHERE       def.Description = '[redacted]'
AND         deff.FieldID = 28
AND         deff.Show = 0) build
ON room.BuildingID = build.Value1
WHERE b.DateAdded > DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AND (StatusID = 1 OR StatusID = 16);
```

Heidi: "Duration for 1 query: 1.015 sec."

SSMS: "00:00:01"

I am obviously green, but my understanding was that the execution plan was determined server side and not application side. This leads me to suspect that there is some sort of overhead in Heidi with respect to this query (simpler queries execute MUCH faster so the overhead would not be universal).

This is just a point of curiosity for me. I am still learning. Can anyone offer a clue about what I can check/google/research to try to understand this?

Thanks!

EDIT:  The times I have reported do not agree with my statement that the SSMS time is 1/10 that of Heidi.  They are both approximately 1 second.  My subjective wait time (wall clock time) between execution and display is MUCH faster (and much less than 1 second) in SSMS.  Can this be due to SSMS caching the results?

Comment: You say *" it takes approximately 10 times longer than executing the identical query in SSMS"* however, then times you give are `1.015 sec` for Heidi and `00:00:01` for SSMS. That;s not 10 times slower, that's 0.015 seconds longer (or 1.5% longer). Considering, however, that the value you took from SSMS is accurate to 1 second, and Heidi 1/100th of a second, SSMS could easily have taken longer.

Comment: If you want timing data independent of the client used, you can use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. Per Larnu, the difference is actually negligible in this case. If you measured 10 seconds longer in wall clock time, that should be completely determined by how quickly the client side actually rendered the results (SSMS slows down tremendously when you're fetching a large amount of rows in a grid, for example, just from updating the GUI).

Comment: @Larnu You are correct.  Because the subjective wait time in my seat is much longer for Heidi, I mistakenly misinterpreted the SSMS time to be 1/10 of a second.

However it is true that I experience a much longer delay between execution and seeing the results in Heidi.  In SSMS the results are "instantaneous" subjectively, whereas in Heidi I do experience a full second of waiting.  

Is it possible that SSMS has cached the results and writes to display quickly while still displaying the vanilla execution time?

And thanks for pointing out my misapprehension.

Comment: If you are using a HeidiSQL nightly build between 10.2.0.5729 and 10.2.0.5747, then you are a victim of a bug I introduced for [issue 685](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/685) . I already fixed that, please update in that case.

Comment: @DanQuixote did you give it a try and update HeidiSQL to the latest build, to see if that's faster?

Comment: @Anse I'm sorry for my slow response.  Yes! On the current release I am no longer experiencing this performance difference between Heidi and SSMS!  Thank you for updating.